# Using async_read and asio::transfer_exactly (non-Boost Asio)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I use non-Boost Asio in asynchronous way. I send data via network in packages which have format like this:

- size of package: uint64
- body package: uchar * (size of package)

So when I want to receive package firstly I wait for package size using **asio::transfer_exactly** helper:

```
asio::async_read(socket, buffer, asio::transfer_exactly(sizeof(uint64_t)), handler);
```

Handler signature looks like this:

```
void handler(const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
```

But sometimes this handler is executing with *bytes_transferred = 0* (*error* doesn't contain any errors) and *buffer* doesn't contain necessary data (size of package). After that further transmission hangs.

There are no other reading operations from socket, so *async_read* is calling exclusive.

What can be reason of this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure that `buffer` is larger than 8 bytes?

Comment: Yes, it is asio::streambuf and this trouble happens sometimes.

Comment: Are you creating a new `streambuf` for each read, or calling `consume` before re-using it?

Comment: I create new instance of `asio::streambuf` for every new package.

Comment: I face the same problem with Boost 1.58 on Ubuntu 16.04 (amd64). The only difference I see so far is using `std::vector` as target buffer. The interesting thing is that on another machine (arm64) issue does not arise.